# Importing AngularJS Into Typescript as AMD

Tags: angularjs, typescript, amd

I am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://github.com/abogartz/typescript-amd-gulp-example) on github to stup a build process for typescript and angularjs.  I have to be honest I am really struggling.  I took the project from github and added angularjs to the bower file, the typings and the lib directory with the angular.ts file (following how JQuery was setup):

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>

var angular= angular;
export = angular;
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt the following I have no luck in getting my app module registered:

```
import JQuery = require("../lib/JQuery");
import angular = require("../lib/angular");

class A{
  public add(number1:number, number2:number):number{
    return number1+number2;
  }

  public colorBG():void{
    var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
    $("body").css({"background-color":"black"})
  }
}

export = A;
```

I am seeing conflicting information online about this being type of import for angular not being possible as an AMD but the definitely typed typing file has it exported as an AMD so what gives?  The gulp build process completes successfully but the call to angular.module complains it is not a function in the chrome console.  Is there a trick to getting angular into typescript so I can concatenate one output file for my html?  I have tried requirejs for AMD, tsify/browserify for commonjs and I cannot get either to work.  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

Install type definitions for dependencies:

```
tsd install angular jquery --save
```

Install dependencies using npm:

```
npm init
npm install angular jquery --save
```

This means that your dependencies will not be under the `lib` folder. They will be under the `node_modules` folder.

Your `/typings/tsd.d.ts` file needs to contain references to all your dependencies:

```
/// <reference path="./jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="./angular/angular.d.ts"/>
```

Then you can reference the `/typings/tsd.d.ts` from your modules:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>

import { $ } from "jquery";
import { angular } from "angular";

class A {
  public add(number1:number, number2:number):number{
    return number1+number2;
  }

  public colorBG():void{
    var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
    $("body").css({"background-color":"black"})
  }
}

export { A };
```

Since TypeScript 1.5 you should use the [ES6 module syntax](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

### Update

Since 2.0 the recomended solution is npm:

```
$ npm install jquery --save
$ npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

Typings and tsd are no longer required.

Comment: For what it is worth I followed this approach and the typescript will not compile complaining that Module jquery has no exported member $ and module angular has no exported member angular (error TS2305)

Comment: Try with the old syntax for import with  `import $ = require("jquery");` and `import $ = require("angular");` and export `export = A;`

Comment: Many `.d.ts` files are not ready to work with the ES6 syntax maybe that is the  problem

Comment: While I have your attention is there a good way to get angularjs and all custom code part of the same javascript output file?  Module loaders for amd (require) or commonjs (browserify) do not seem to behave well for me.  I got browserify working today but then the sourcemaps to the TS were broke, it has been one problem after another.

Comment: You can use [internal modules](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-internal-and-external-modules/) Working with modules and Browserify can be complicated, I understand your frustration but I would encourage you too keep researching and learning until it works because it is technically more correct than using internal modules.

Comment: The old syntax `import angular = require('angular')` worked for me.

Comment: Installed `@types/angular` via npm then used `import * as angular from 'angular';`